# (ChromeCookiesView) can't read 'value' for my chrome cookies file

Tags: windows, google-chrome, cookies, httpcookie

Everything looks normal when using this code

`ChromeCookiesView.exe /shtml cookies.html`

The problem is when I make the program decode a custom cookie file

`ChromeCookiesView.exe /CookiesFile C:\users\example\desktop\example\cookies /shtml cookies.html`

The problem is that all fields appear except for the "Value" field, which is empty

[normal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzFGh.png)(**The First Command**)

[The output contains a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBQbP.png)(**The second Command**)

Is there a solution for this?